# Nothing returned when using 32 bit Python os.popen on a 64 Bit Windows 7 System

Tags: python, windows-7, popen

I am trying to use the following commands to run a check for bitlocker encryption on a 64 Bit Windows 7 system:

```
import os
os.popen('C:\Windows\System32\manage-bde.exe -status c:').read()
```

and it returns '' (nothing).

I have also tried to use subprocess.Popen with the same results.

This is a 32 bit version of Python 2.6.6 running on a 64 bit Windows 7 machine. When I use a 64 bit version of Python, both os.popen and subprocess.Popen work, but I am unable to use 64 bit Python as I have many 32 bit systems to support and py2exe will not support bundling on a 64 bit platform.

Does anyone know if I can get either subprocess.Popen or os.popen to work on a 64 bit Windows system using a 32 bit version of Python? I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Alternately, if anyone knows how I can check for full bitlocker encryption on a Windows 7 system without the benefit of using manage-bde.exe, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Did you try running the same command from the command-line? Did it work?

Comment: Sorry. I should have pointed that out. I am able to use this command from the command line without any issue.

Comment: "\" is an escape char.  use forward slashes, or double backslashes instead

Comment: @Corey Goldberg: Using either double back slashes or single forward slashes produces nothing as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

manage-bde.exe is in the "real" System32 directory. 32 Bit applications are automatically redirected to %windir%\SysWOW64, when they try to access it. You can access it via the **SysNative** alias:

```
import os
os.popen(r'C:\Windows\SysNative\manage-bde.exe -status c:').read()
```

Comment: Do you have to include the full path? Could you not let the system PATH do the work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the output of manage-bde is kind of hacky. The output format could easily change in future Windows releases and your script would break.

The cleaner, more maintainable alternative would be to use the BitLocker WMI Provider, Win32_EncryptableVolume. Specifically, the [GetProtectionStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376448%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

As it was already pointed you can access 64-bit applications from "real" System32 directory via the **Sysnative** alias (i.e. %windir%\Sysnative). But please note that %windir%\Sysnative is defined only for 32 bit applications and is not valid for 64 bit ones: "64-bit applications cannot use the **Sysnative** alias as it is a virtual directory not a real one" ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx)).